# How to interpret state and log files written by preload program in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ubuntu-12.04

Preload is a program which prefetches files from the disk needed by various applications to reduce application startup time. It seems to be very popular and [useful](http://techthrob.com/2009/03/02/drastically-speed-up-your-linux-system-with-preload/) (just google preload+linux) but the documentation or man page seems to be bit sparse.

I am trying to understand the meaning of various values saved in log (`/var/log/preload.log`) and state (`/var/lib/preload/preload.state`) files written by preload, so that I can fine-tune which directories to preload or otherwise. I am attaching *small section* of the files from my computer below.

So, What are the values in different columns? Also one of the line in log file says `0kb available for preloading, using 0kb of it` - What does this mean?

### /var/log/preload.log

```
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] state scanning begin
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] state log dump requested
persistent state stats:
preload time = 11173110
num exes = 215
num bad exes = 0
num maps = 8554
runtime state stats:
num running exes = 72
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] state log dump done
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] state scanning end
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] state predicting begin
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0009796222   /usr/NX/bin/nxnode
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0003984986   /usr/bin/Xvnc4
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0000742425   /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-ps
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0003784312   /usr/bin/mate-control-center
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0002042447   /usr/bin/mate-session-properties
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0024875406   /usr/bin/wine64-preloader
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0015284860   /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0015595207   /usr/bin/pluma
ln(prob(~EXE)) =        -0.0103913330   /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] 0kb available for preloading, using 0kb of it
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] nothing to readahead
[Fri Jan 10 17:35:13 2014] state predicting end
[Fri Jan 10 17:36:28 2014] state updating begin
[Fri Jan 10 17:36:28 2014] state updating end
```

### /var/lib/preload/preload.state

```
PRELOAD 0.6.4   11173710
MAP     1       10      217088  2093056 -1      file:///usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstffmpeg.so
MAP     2       351450  536576  2097152 -1      file:///usr/lib/libreoffice/program/libxstor.so
MAP     3       7335780 0       16384   -1      file:///usr/lib/totem/plugins/screensaver/libscreensaver.so
MAP     4       10      352256  8192    -1      file:///usr/lib/libnm-util.so.2.3.0
MAP     9       8786090 274432  4096    -1      file:///usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.0.401.0
MAP     6       7335780 12288   4096    -1      file:///usr/lib/totem/plugins/screensaver/libscreensaver.so
MAP     7       8786090 0       24576   -1      file:///usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
MAP     8       8786090 20480   4096    -1      file:///usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
MAP     5       8786090 0       278528  -1      file:///usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libibus-1.0.so.0.401.0
```

PS: Please excuse lack of references/links. I tried to write a better question with more reference and few images but I did not had enough reputations to post them.

Comment: Normally preload doesn't need to be configured. The configuration file is /etc/preload.conf ... More info there: https://www.linux.com/blog/using-preload-speed-linux

Answer (score 0):

Without digging into the source code you're probably not going to get a good answer here. Preload has not been updated since 2009 (and was initially a Google Summer of Code project from 2005).

From a [2009 blog post I found](https://web.archive.org/web/20130810041104/http://techthrob.com/2009/03/02/drastically-speed-up-your-linux-system-with-preload/) the opinion of the blog's author is:

> The beautiful thing about Preload, however, is that you can ignore
> these files completely; you might want to check up on the log every
> once and a while, just to make sure that it’s running, but Preload
> will happily sit in the background and stay out of your way.

My thoughts are that you should just let this one go...
[See also...](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Preload#Preload)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1099177)

Comment: I think that I did include the “essential” part.